# In XML, is order important?

Tags: xml

Is the order that elements of a common parent appear in XML a meaningful piece of data captured by the XML document, or is order not specified as being meaningful? For example, consider the two XML documents:

```
<people>
 <person name="sam"/>
 <person name="juni"/>
</people>
```

and

```
<people>
 <person name="juni"/>
 <person name="sam"/>
</people>
```

Are these documents considered to represent **identical** data, or is the difference in order captured?

Answer (score 67):

Order of elements is significant in XML, so in your example the two documents are different. Attribute order is not significant, though.

```
<people>
  <person name="kathy" id="1"/>
</people>
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
<people>
  <person id="1" name="kathy"/>
</people>
```

Comment: so if you have <Element><Subelement1 id="2"/><SomeThingElse id="3"/></element> You'd say that order of the subelements matters, even though they're different types?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The order of elements is always significant regardless of what they are.

Comment: You mention in a comment below that the significance of the order of elements is explicitly stated in the XML Specification. Could you add this source to your answer? I believe that the spec in fact does *not* guarantee (sibling) element order. This is also stated in the article linked in the answer by Unwind.

Comment: See 2.1.1 and 2.2.4 in http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/ and note 'unordered' under 2.2.5.

Comment: Without maintaining order, we cannot use common methods such as getFirstChild sensibly.

Answer (score 29):

They are not identical - Whether the sequence *matters* is up to the program or user that processes it. For example, the sequence of elements in an XHTML document determine how they are displayed in a browser, and search engines use the position in the document to judge relative importance of the data.

Comment: Yeah I knew XHTML would come up. I'm not sure that's a good example, because isn't XHTML not fully XML compliant?

Comment: Absolutely it is. That's the raison d'etre of XHTML.

Comment: XHTML is XML compliant, however XML is not XHTML compliant.

Answer (score 27):

The order is *potentially* important, but it depends on what's being transmitted.

In XHTML, for example, the order is *extremely* important - if you had sibling paragraphs in a random order, it would be very confusing!

In many other cases, it's unimportant.

XML is just a way of representing a tree of nodes. XML itself says that the order is important: APIs must preserve the order, for example - but it's up to whatever produces/interprets the data to *really* care about the order or not.

The XML specification effectively has to "err on the side of ordering" - it's easy to ignore ordering if you don't care about it, but it's a pain to reconstruct ordering if APIs decide to switch things around. (You'd have to put the order into attributes etc.)

Comment: Do you happen to have a clear source for "APIs must preserve the order"? http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#infoitem.document clearly says that element order is part of an XML document's information content, but it also says that that document does not constitute "a minimum set of information that must be returned by an XML processor." Is there any clear constraint in the specs that I would be violating if I produced an XML processor that did not provide any access to element order information?

Comment: @bames53: Well that's an infoset specification rather than the XML specification... but even then, the XML spec more closely defines what constitutes a valid document than how APIs return information. That said, it does say that an element has a *sequence* of child elements rather than a set. Put it this way: if you produce an XML processor that didn't preserve ordering, you'd be *hugely* reducing the number of possible uses for it. If you've got one specific use in mind, and it makes your life easier, then fine - but give clear and *huge* warnings that it does this, to avoid surprising folks.

Comment: "the XML spec more closely defines what constitutes a valid document" The XML spec does say "This specification describes the required behavior of an XML processor in terms of how it must read XML data _and the information it must provide to the application._" I agree that not providing the ordering would make an XML Processor largely useless, but I was wondering to what degree it's actually a conformance requirement. Thanks.

Comment: @bames53: That's an interesting quote - unfortunately in that case, it's not terribly well written in terms of that side of things :( It's much easier to find the "valid document" areas than "this is how data is provided to applications". Sigh.

Answer (score 7):

From purely an XML validity point of view, it depends on the schema, if any, that describes what the rules are for formatting the XML.

That said, order must be preserved (see 2.1.1 in http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) but whether it's "important" to an application is up to its author.

Within a schema, order can be made unimportant with the use of the `xs:all` compositor, though I'm not sure that this impacts the preservation of captured order, i.e. I'd still expect the order at origin/serialization to be maintained by XML processors.

However, in 1.0 this compositor adds a restriction on the child elements so that they must occur 0 or 1 times. In XSD 1.1, this restriction is removed, making it easier to contractually specify that order is not important, effectively `xs:all` has become the unordered version of `xs:sequence`.

Because of the overly-restrictive 1.0 `xs:all` compositor, the ordered `xs:sequence` compositor had to be used. Thus, order was often artificially imposed.

Adoption of 1.1 by vendors of validator libraries is slow.

As such, APIs need to consider order when being evolved with new elements. I am not aware of any XML serialization framework that can work with 1.1 and you have to assume your clients will be using 1.0 and will validate the 1.1 incoming messages with 1.0 rules and choke.

Luke

Comment: +1 for mentioning xs:sequence. If an xsd can specify the order of elements is meaningful, any technology that deals with XML must be aware of the order of elements and be able to preserve this ordering.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord.html), the 1.0 version of the standard doesn't even require that parsers report siblings in the order they appear in the document. In that light, they would not be considered different, as both children are there. Perhaps this has changed, so that other answers are for newer versions of XML, though.

Comment: If you need to ensure order you can add 'index=' attributes to each entry

Answer (score 5):

While XML attribute ordering is not significant as far as the XML standard is concerned, the textual representation of XML does by necessity place the attributes in a specific order. This can be an issue for things like XML Signature, which generates a digital signature for XML documents. A different attribute order would generate a different signature, which clearly is wrong.

For this (and other) reasons, there is now a standard for XML Canonicalization, which defines rules for re-organising XML documents such that they retain the same information content, but have things like whitespace, namespace declarations and attributes rearranged in a predictable way.

From [xml.com](http://webservices.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2002/09/18/c14n.html?page=2)

> Canonical XML requires the inclusion
>   of namespace declarations and
>   attributes in ascending lexicographic
>   order.

Answer (score 4):

The [XML 1.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) does not say anything about the order of elements with equal names as children of the same parent element. So it seems, the issue is undefined.

However, most XML parsers and APIs will preserve the sequence as given in the textual representation. So, it is possible to implement applications that care about the element order. And the de facto answer to your question is: Yes, the order matters. The two examples are different.

Looking more closely, you'll need to eveluate what your use case is. If your XML needs to interoperate with different (maybe 3rd party) applications, you should always assume that order matters. If you have total control on the producing and consuming application, then you might relax this rule.

As always, you'll have to judge.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference. You can use various XML API's to process elements in sequence or find an element by index. Of course order may not matter in your particular example, but that depends on the semantics of the data.

Comment: Yeah I am aware that many APIs preserve the order. But I wonder if this behavior is required by the XML specification.

Comment: Each XML element can have a content model. The content models for your elements are very simple, but you can create very complex content models in XML involving sequences or lists of elements. The XHTML <html> element should contain a <head> and a <body> element in that order. In that sense the XML specification allows you to specify order. If you have a content model of a sequence (zero or more) <person> elements it is up to you if the order has any semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The order is captured.

Answer (score 1):

I think those should be considered identical, but it's really up to the software or person reading it to decide. XML is just a way of writing out data. The application determines how that data is used and therefore much of the meaning.

If your application reads in all of the person elements and then alphabetizes them by name, then the order in the XML document is meaningless. If your application reads them in and assigns seats in the same order the people appear in the XML, then the order is very important.

It's up to the application that uses the data. If the order is important, it should be described in the specs for people generating the files.

Comment: The XML specification is explicit on this, the order of elements is significant.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord.html

Maybe the discussion in the article will help to answer your question. Since your question is somewhat open, I am not sure if it covers you concerns.