# Good idea or bad idea, to use non-deterministic ordering of xml elements in the output of a REST service?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soa

Hash.to_xml and other such Railsisms may result in element orderings being different in the output of a REST service. XML Elems are order sensitive, so this would not be a problem for JSON or XML attributes.

What aspect of service definition best practices is this breaking that makes me think it is a smell ??

Comment: "XML Elems are order sensitive".  Not universally true: this is totally dependent on the DTD or XSD.

Comment: Not totally dependent - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131495/in-xml-is-order-important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking of REST over HTTP, caching is a big leverage. Even if the inside is "semantically" the same, if it differs structurally then you could end up with a lot of Cache misses (e.g. done with [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)). Of course it depends "how" the comparison is done, but imho most Cache implementations use simple hashing of the returned payload as comparing-entity.

So if Caching is important, I would tend to spit out also same structure for "semantically" same documents.

Answer (score 0):

non-deterministic ordering would be my expectation -- meaning, that I would not depend on anything else.

It's nice if you can provide a deterministic XML for simple diffing, but that's more in static XML then in service responses.

Comment: Can you cite on what you have based that expectation ? I've heard that expectation before, justified by the fact that in ruby     {:x=>1, :b=>2}.to_xml may come out in any order

Comment: It's not just that -- XML is specifically not order dependent.  There is nothing in XML schema definitions or XSD's that let's you say that your nodes need to be in an order -- therefore, order just has no meaning in XML.  The same is true for attributes in a node.  These aspects of XML is what sets my expectation.

Comment: Lou, to refute one of your points: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp (this allows you to say your nodes must appear in an order). Also the xml spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) agrees that attributes' order is insignificant, but nothing in the spec indicates that the same is true for elements, in fact the existence of the xs:sequence element in schema (and no corresponding one for attributes) refutes the second part of your claim.