# Why is node order important in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been dealing with an API recently that requires nodes of the XML document to be in a particular order. I was wondering why they feel the need to enforce this when I can find absolutely no reason why things should be like this.

For intance, this would be correct (xml greatly simplified)

```
<transaction>
    <address>1 main st</address>
    <amount>100</amount>
    <orderId>1234</orderId>
</transaction>
```

but this would return an error

```
<transaction>
    <address>1 main st</address>
    <orderId>1234</orderId>
    <amount>100</amount>
</transaction>
```

At first I thought it would be so that they can store things in a list/array form and have the indices always refer to the same node. I understand why sending sibling nodes that have the same name in the same order is important as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131495/in-xml-is-order-important). However, some nodes can be left out:

```
<transaction>
    <amount>100</amount>
    <orderId>1234</orderId>
</transaction>
```

So in the third example, amount and orderId would now be at [0] and [1] instead of at [1] and [2] in the first (correct) example.

Another thought would be that they process the XML as a string and require that they always know what nodes come after each other, but again since omitting nodes is allowed, that theory doesn't make sense.

Can anyone explain to me why the order in which I give nodes matters? Or am I just dealing with an API that is old and grumpy?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes or close votes here.

Answer (score 20):

Node order obviously matters in XML like this:

```
<p>
   <span>This wouldn't make much sense</span>
   <span>if the order of these nodes were reversed.</span>
</p>
```

It's less obvious in XML like what you provided, which appears to be some kind of serialization format.  But objects whose property setters have side effects can fail if the properties aren't set in the right order.

Imagine a class with a private `Person` field that exposes `PersonID` and `Name` properties.  The `PersonID` setter creates the private instance of `Person`, and the `Name` setter sets the `Name` property on the private `Person` field.  In this case, setting `Name` before you set `PersonID` fails, because `Person` doesn't exist yet.

This is a case where implementing a schema that requires `PersonID` to appear before `Name` in the XML keeps this error from happening, at the cost of forcing other developers to do things that are apparently nonsensical.

Tthe obvious thing to do in situations like this is to find the developer who wrote that class and beat him.  This is rarely possible, though it's interesting to contemplate a world in which it were.

Answer (score 8):

One reason XML node order can matter is where an application is using a streaming parser.  Having dependent elements in the expected order can allow the application to be significantly more efficient processing the XML data.  This is especially true for applications processing large scale XML data.

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in **XML-DTD/Schema**. The underlying schema so defined in the API results in the error. Though I suppose I donot wish to teach XML here, still a look at the following will make things clear.

XML has two points to be considered:

- **Well Formed XML:** perfect syntax
- **Valid XML:** perfectly valid against a DTD (Document Type Definition) / Schema

**Points about DTD:**
Suggested DTD upon your question:

```
<!DOCTYPE transaction
[
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT amount (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT orderid (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

The above is a suggested DTD upon the structure you provided in the question. Since you are dealing with a particular API, it has such type of structure already defined in it. Alternative to this is the **XML schema**.

**Points about XML Schema:**

```
<xs:element name="transaction">    
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="orderid" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Currently, **XML schema** are used **instead of DTDs** as they are far more superior in defining the data structure for their users and provide an **object-oriented approach**.

Comment: +1 Could you give an example of how the DTD and schema would be modified in order to make `address`, `amount` and `orderid` valid in any order? Would it be a more complex DTD/schema? If so then this would be one possible reason why the developers have enforced the order...

Comment: The answer for the ordering lies in the fact that these files are parsed from TAG to TAG. The concerned application which parses the file, will parse the file in the sequence provided in the schema. Well if you build your custom parser library, you can definitely change the ordering.. just to make the parsing logic more complex!!

Answer (score 2):

It's faster and simpler for code to depend on the order of elements.

It can also prevent certain issues of ambiguity when the order is permitted to be arbitrary.

Besides, XML isn't meant as much for human readers, as it is meant for computer programs to consume. Computers don't mind doing things in order.

Comment: But my issue here is wouldn't it take MORE effort on the part of the developer/library to validate the correct order of the elements?

Comment: It might be more effort to validate it, but less to _assume_ the order.

Answer (score 1):

An enforced order makes it simpler for the consumer, which can look like:

```
consumeTransation:
    consumeAddressIfPresent;
    consumeAmountIfPresent;
    consumeOrderIDIfPresent;
```

More significantly, the use of **XML Schema** for structure definition **makes order more likely to be a requirement**. That's because XML Schema has richer support for ordered lists (`xs:sequence`) that for unordered lists (`xs:all`). The latter have occurrence restrictions, are more difficult to validate, and are not extensible in the way sequences are. Some of that is improved in XML Schema 1.1, but most tools/APIs aren't there, yet.