# Not all properties are being sent or received in a WCF call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am having a frustrating time debugging my new WCF service. Issue is with a certain DataContract. Seems like on de-serialization on the server side after a certain property something happens and the rest are not set. I have looked at the generated xsd schemas generated from the metadata and all seems ok. I have used Fiddler to snoop the soap packet sent and leaving the client all data is present. I have even set the Order parameter to the DataContract attribute to see if i could see a pattern but never did. I have also compared the DataMember name with the one in the message and they all match. The only pattern i found was this:

Here is the xsd definition for the DataContract object in question:

```
<xs:complexType name="Attachment">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fileName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="guid" type="ser:guid"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="obsDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="operation" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="originalFileName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="title" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="type" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is the DataContract object:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.myns.com")]
public class Attachment
{
    public enum AttachmentSortOrder { Date, FileType }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid guid;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime dateTime;
    [DataMember]
    public string operation;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime obsDate;
    [DataMember]
    public string originalFileName;
    [DataMember]
    public string fileName;
    [DataMember]
    public string title;
    [DataMember]
    public string type;
    [DataMember]
    public string description;
}
```

Seems like all properties after obsDate does not get set for some reason.

WHY?

Comment: Can you post the XML which you're using to deserialize (and which causes the properties not to be set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to see the SOAP and also know whether the client is .NET.

I've seen something like this happen using a non .NET client. Your xsd specifies a [`sequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256089.aspx) - which is be determined using the `Order` attribute or defaulting to alphabetical order.  Some clients seem to treat this as an [`all`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256182.aspx) element; they appear to take the view that "it's all the same XML" (see [In XML, is order important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131495/in-xml-is-order-important)).

So in summary, check whether the SOAP elements are in the correct sequence matching your XSD.

Comment: Yes the client is .NET but 2.0. I have basically rewritten a legacy asp.net web service (.asmx) using WCF. I cannot change the consumer/host. I have played around with the order and have tried to match the incoming message but it didn't work. I will try again though. I will also post the incoming SOAP message in a bit.

Comment: Matching the **DataContract** objects **DataMember** Order to the same as the incoming message fixed it. Not too sure what i did wrong when i was playing with this last night.

Answer (score 2):

Enable WCF Error logging and findout the root cause via [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)