# Issue with C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

We have a C# webservice where in the request comes in from another application. We have a a method A(B b). The structure of B is

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
Public Class B
{
  [Datamember]
  public List<int> D {get;set;}
  [Datamember (isrequired=true)]
  public string C {get;set;}
}
```

We now are facing an issue , when the calling application passes C ahead of D in the request , we do not recieve D , but when C is passed after D is passed , we get both values correctly. Is there an order

Comment: What do you mean is there an order?

Comment: [Yes, order is important](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See also [In XML, is order important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131495/in-xml-is-order-important).

Answer (score 0):

DataMemberAttribute has the property [`Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx).

Also see this duplicate SO question, [WCF Datacontract, some fields do not deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519240/wcf-datacontract-some-fields-do-not-deserialize)